# Updating data in a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting data from backend part and write it into a variable. Then I use ng-repeat and print data into my view. When my view and component loaded and data successful printed I want to add a new element. But when I write an element into variable, for some reason it can't be reflected in my view. 
Here's my component:

```
var pl = angular.module('phoneList');

pl.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('bookslist').then(function (response) {
    $scope.phones = response.data;   // GETTING DATA
});


$scope.addNew = function (answerForm) { // ADD NEW ELEMENT 
    if(answerForm.$valid){

        var book = {  
            name: $scope.name,
            author: $scope.author,
            publish_year: $scope.publish_year,
            description: $scope.description
        };

         $scope.phones.push(book); // Adding an element to the end of object. It's will be add but I can't to show it in a view

        $http.post('addbook', book).then(function (response) { // SAVE DATA 
            $scope.errors = response.data;  
        });
        $http.get('bookslist').then(function (response) {  // Tried to get all data one more time, but it's also doesn't work:( 
            $scope.phones = response.data;
        });
    }
};
});
```

This is my view file

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2">

        <ul class="phones"">
            <div class="row" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
                <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp"
                    class="thumbnail">
                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <a href="#!/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb">
                            <img ng-src="{{phone.author}}" alt="{{phone.name}}"/>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#!/phones/{{phone.id}}">{{phone.name}}</a>

                        <p>{{phone.description}}</p>
                        <p style="color:gray;">Publish date: {{phone.publish_year}}</p>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-9" style="position:relative; bottom: 70px;">
                            <a href="#!/edit/{{phone.id}}">
                                <button class="btn btn-info" style="display: inline-block">Edit</button>
                            </a>
                            <a href="" ng-click="removeBook(phone.id)" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" style="display: inline-block">Delete</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So in the first time when I get data all alright, but if I delete or add new element then data doesn't update. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse the [Promisse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) don't wait for execute, try this

```
pl.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('bookslist').then(function (response) {
    $scope.phones = response.data;   // GETTING DATA
});


$scope.addNew = function (answerForm) { // ADD NEW ELEMENT 
    if(answerForm.$valid){

        var book = {  
            name: $scope.name,
            author: $scope.author,
            publish_year: $scope.publish_year,
            description: $scope.description
        };

         $scope.phones.push(book); // Adding an element to the end of object. It's will be add but I can't to show it in a view

        $http.post('addbook', book).then(function (response) { // SAVE DATA 
            $scope.errors = response.data;
            $http.get('bookslist').then(function (response) {  // Tried to get all data one more time, but it's also doesn't work:( 
              $scope.phones = response.data;
            });
        });
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I still have to refresh a page  to look at result. Maybe there are more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because the view still contains the old reference. Please use `angular.extend` for the proper reference update. Check the updated code below:

```
var pl = angular.module('phoneList');

pl.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.phones = [];
$http.get('bookslist').then(function (response) {
    $scope.phones.length = 0;
    angular.extend($scope.phones, response.data);// GETTING DATA
});


$scope.addNew = function (answerForm) { // ADD NEW ELEMENT 
    if(answerForm.$valid){

        var book = {  
            name: $scope.name,
            author: $scope.author,
            publish_year: $scope.publish_year,
            description: $scope.description
        };
        var tmpObj = {};
        $scope.phones.push(book); // Adding an element to the end of object. It's will be add but I can't to show it in a view
        angular.extend(tmpObj, $scope.phones);
        $scope.phones.length = 0;
        angular.extend($scope.phones, tmpObj);

        $http.post('addbook', book).then(function (response) { // SAVE DATA 
            $scope.errors = response.data;  
        });
        $http.get('bookslist').then(function (response) {  // Tried to get all data one more time, but it's also doesn't work:( 
            $scope.phones.length = 0;
            angular.extend($scope.phones, response.data);
        });
    }
};
});
```

Comment: No, nothing. But I successfully recieve data from backend. Also I use angularjs v1.5.11

Comment: Have you used $scope.apply and "controller as" syntax.

Comment: also did you used $ctrl.phones in view.

Comment: <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp" line is wrong, use <li ng-repeat="phone in phones"> for testing, later add the filter

Comment: When I have been writing this post no. But later I add app.directive where I used $scope.apply. Could this be a problem?

Comment: It could be, better try <li ng-repeat="phone in phones"> first

Comment: change <div class="row" ng-controller="ListCtrl as ctl">
                <li ng-repeat="phone in ctl.phones"> the scope problem is little tricky.

Comment: These are all steps as I described in the comments. Data should not disappeared.

Comment: I'll try to create a new project and use it on empty project. Thank you for help!

Comment: One more thing does your code have <body ng-app="phoneList">

Answer (score 0):

I wasted two days on this view not updating on model change bug...
Initialize all your scope variables like this from now

```
 $scope.data = {};
 $scope.data.phones = null;
```

When getting data use

```
 $scope.data.phones = response.data;
```

Then just use $scope.data.phones in view. And when updating update

```
 $scope.data.phones.push(book);
```

This will work